# How do I install packages in TeXLive on Windows 10

Tags: packages, texlive, installing

I tried to install packages like numinsec.sty to Texlive on Windows 10 by copying the files in ‪`C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\numinsec.sty`. But Texlive can not find it when compiling. What is the problem?

Is the installation of packages on TeXLive similar to MiKTex in which you just copy files into a localTexmf folder and add that folder to MiKTex directory?  Thanks.

Comment: Note that numinsec is already part of TeX Live (at least TeX Live 2020).

Comment: No, I am using TeX Live 2017

Comment: Did you run mktexlsr?

Comment: No I do not know mktexlsr

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/texhash.html

Comment: Yes, I think it needs refresh of directory, but I do not know how to. Also the directory of installed package C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex, is there, and I do not create it. But it seems still need refresh?

Comment: Why are you still using TeXLive 2017 in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. First copy the package files to `\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex` folder. Then launch TeXLive Manager to update the database. For TeXLive after 2019, select from the Actions menu *Regenerate filename database*. For TeXLive before 2019, select from the Actions menu *Update filename database*.

Comment: If you use LyX, do the following after what Hermes explained: use the menu of LyX: Tools > Reconfigure.  Then restart LyX.

Answer (score 5):

You can also:

- Press Win-X
- Select `Windows Powershell (Admin)`
- (If you’re wondering where to put the packages) At the command prompt, run `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` to find the directory to put your downloaded files in.
- Run `texhash`

You can run any other command-line utilities you want this way.  For example, `tlmgr update --self --all`, `updmap-sys` or `luaotfload-tool -u -p -v`.

Comment: Is it also necessary to launch TeXLive Manager and select Actions > Regenerate filename database?

Comment: @RodolfoOviedo I believe that runs `texhash`. I’m more used to the command line, but that probably would work too?